# Does canonical projection of commutative rings(R to R/I) always send prime ideals to prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

R is a commutative ring with 1, I is an ideal of R. Consider the canonical projection f: R to R/I. Suppose p is a prime ideal of R then is f(p) always prime? I think if ab+I$\in$f(P) with ab$\in$ p, thus a or b$\in$ p, thus a+I or b+I $\in$ f(p).Is that a right proof? I think maybe there is a problem, because the prime ideals of R/I are in bijection with the prime ideals of R containing I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a problem and you seem to have the right intuition as to where it is. For example, let us look at the canonical projection $\pi\colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $(3) \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal, but $\pi((3)) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a prime ideal. (Note that $(3)$ is a prime ideal not containing the ideal that was factored out.)

The example shows that your proof must be wrong. Indeed, the mistake is the very first step: from $ab + I \in f(p)$ it does not in general follow that $ab \in p$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think the problem is the image is not always proper.

Comment: @Joseph There are also counterexamples where the image is proper. For example, take $\pi\colon k[X,Y] \to k[X,Y]/(X,Y^2)$, where $k$ is an integral domain. Then $(X) \subset k[X,Y]$ is a prime ideal, but $\pi((X)) = (0)$ is not a prime ideal (as $Y^2 = 0$ but $Y \neq 0$ in the quotient).

Comment: @ c_c_chaos, thank you, but here (x,$y^2$) is not an ideal of k[x,y]

Comment: @Joseph: In my comment $(X,Y^2)$ denotes the _ideal generated by_ the set $\{ X, Y^2 \}$. Does this address your concern?

Comment: @ c_c_chaos That makes sense, thank you.